# How to render circle with constant size in perceptive projection?

Tags: opengl, projection, perspective, glpointsize

I want to render a circle with constant size in pixels, regardless of the item depth (in perspective projection).

When I use glPointSize there is a small difference in size that correlates to the depth (near objects are larger then far ones).

The function description states:

> The specified point size is multiplied with a distance attenuation
>   factor and clamped to the specified point size range, and further
>   clamped to the implementation-dependent point size range to produce
>   the derived point size using.

Is there a way to completely rasterize a point?

Comment: What OpenGL version are you using? In the latest versions `glPointSize` literally means the size in pixels. (I'm looking at OpenGL 4.5 spec and it doesn't have the phrasing you quoted.)

Comment: I have openGL version 4.0.
The description is from gl2 documentation see link:
https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPointSize.xml


But I get changes in pixels when using glPointSize

Comment: Why are you using a perspective projection here?  The whole point of a perspective projection is that things are smaller farther away. Your use case makes me think that an orthographic matrix might be needed.

Comment: The perspective is intentional. I need to keep some objects (circles) in the scene with constant size,